# MYSQL QUERY : Select 1 rows photo from table for each album

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table with records and it has a table called gallery. I have inserted too many photo and I want to select only 2 random photo from each gallery.

here my structured

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gallery` (
`gallery_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `gallery_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `gallery_name_seo` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `gallery_client` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `gallery_date` date NOT NULL,
  `gallery_type` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `gallery_desc` text,
  `gallery_publish` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N' COMMENT 'Y = Yes & N = No',
  `gallery_added` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `deleted` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and here another table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `gallery_photo` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `id_gallery` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `file_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `file_added` date NOT NULL,
  `deleted` smallint(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=24 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

acctually there many example here but i hard to understand,

how to create query from my problem.?

thanks

Comment: Great. So what's the problem?

Comment: _“and I want to select only 2 photo from each gallery”_ – two what? Oldest, newest, random, … two photos?

Comment: i want show 2 random photo for each gallery..

Comment: Please amend your question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

The following query would give you 1 random photo per `id_gallery`:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM `gallery_photo` ORDER BY RAND()) as `rand_photos`
GROUP BY rand_photos.id_gallery
```

You could `UNION` it with itself to get 2 random photos for each gallery:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM `gallery_photo` ORDER BY RAND()) as `rand_photo1`
GROUP BY rand_photo1.id_gallery
UNION
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * FROM `gallery_photo` ORDER BY RAND()) as `rand_photo2`
GROUP BY rand_photo2.id_gallery
ORDER BY id_gallery
```